# Could not find io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.2.20

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

This is my project and I am trying to use this rxjava library. At the beginning, I added the required dependencies  it is being synced without any fault but when I rebuilt the project it did not work. Here is my build gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.cerentekin.countrylist"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }


}

dependencies {
    def lifeCycleExtensionVersion = '1.1.1'
    def supportVersion = '28.0.0'
    def retrofitVersion = '2.9.0'
    def glideVersion = '4.12.0'
    def rxJavaVersion = '2.2.20'
    def roomVersion = '2.4.2'
    def navVersion = '2.4.1'
    def preferencesVersion = '1.2.0'



    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifeCycleExtensionVersion"

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation "com.android.support:palette-v7:$supportVersion"
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportVersion"

    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofitVersion"

    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glideVersion"

    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rxJavaVersion"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rxJavaVersion"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion"
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.2"

    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navVersion"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navVersion"

    implementation "androidx.preference:preference:$preferencesVersion-ktx"

    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0"

}
```

I have tried rxjava library for the first time but the project is not being synced." Could not find io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.2.20. " it gives me this fault.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same version for **rxjava** and **rxandroid**, two different libraries

The latest **rxandroid** version is **2.1.1** not **2.2.20**

You can check the latest versions of libraries that are uploaded to maven by searching the [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/)

For example the **rxandroid2** versions can be found listed [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.reactivex.rxjava2/rxandroid)